# awk does not end

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have the following code in a file named `awktest1.awk`:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{print "start"}
{print $2, "\t", $5}
END{print "end"} employee.txt
```

where `employee.txt` contains the following data:

```
100  Thomas  Manager    Sales  $5,000 
200  Jason   Developer  Technology  $5,500 
300  Sanjay  Sysadmin   Technology  $7,000 
400  Nisha   Manager    Marketing   $9,500 
500  Randy   DBA        Technology  $6,000
```

I run the `awk` command as:

```
awk -f awktest1.awk
```

but it just prints `start` and does not end. Can anyone help me out with what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Note that by writing: `print $2, "\t", $5` as opposed to `print $2 "\t" $5`,  you're writing the 2nd field followed by OFS (space), TAB, OFS and the 5th field.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error is giving the filename to process in the script; you should remove `employee.txt` from the script and run it as follows

```
awk -f awktest1.awk employee.txt
```

or even, if the script is executable,

```
./awktest1.awk employee.txt
```

The script becomes

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{print "start"}
{print $2, "\t", $5}
END{print "end"}
```

As it is, `awk` is waiting for input from standard input instead of reading from a file. That's why it never ends...

Answer (score 12):

To complement [@Stephen's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/222147), if you wanted to hardcode the name of the input file in the `awk` script, you'd write:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
  ARGC=2
  ARGV[1] = "employee.txt"
  OFS = FS = "\t"
  print "start"
}
{print $2, $5}
END{print "end"}
```

For several files:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
  ARGC=1
  ARGV[ARGC++] = "employee1.txt"
  ARGV[ARGC++] = "employee2.txt"
  ARGV[ARGC++] = "employee3.txt"
  # ...

  # or ARGC=1+split("employee1.txt employee2.txt employee3.txt", ARGV)

  OFS = FS = "\t"
  print "start"
}
{print $2, $5}
END{print "end"}
```

Answer (score 5):

Or if you don't want to pass the filename `employee.txt` as a command line argument, you can do something like this:

#### Code:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
    print "start"
    while((getline <"employee.txt") > 0){
        {print $2, "\t", $5}
    }
    print "end"
}
```